# Flash - wrap animation on timeline into movieclip

Tags: flash

question is about flash IDE (CS5).

Let's say i have a simple motion tween animation present on the timeline. What's the quickest way to wrap this animation into a movieclip?

I have:

timeline containing tweened object with many keyframes

I want:

timeline containing movieclip containing tweened object with many keyframes

don't get me wrong - i'm not a beginner at all - i'm just looking for the quickest way to achiev exactly that, given the described situation (as i have to cleanup some existing files).

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think the best approach is to highlight all the frames of your timeline, right click and select copy frames.  Then create a new symbol and paste the frames into it. Finally clear the main timeline and attach your newly create symbol.